# Best filter to use for modifying custom fields on a post?

Tags: custom-field, filters

What is the best filter for editing custom fields on a post? I am not actually editing the post content but some related fields. Would it be `add_filter('the_content', 'edit_custom_fields');`? It just seems weird to use 'the_content' here, so I am wondering if there is a more appropriate way.

Comment: When is the modification of the custom fields supposed to happen?

Comment: @ialocin On display of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is actually about the [output](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162923/best-filter-to-use-for-modifying-custom-fields-on-a-post#comment235810_162923) as you said in your comment.

I suppose you know, you can do modification like this:

```
// assumed a single result is returned as string
$your_post_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_post_meta', true );
// lets add something
$your_modified_post_meta = 'My post meta: ' . $your_post_meta;
```

So far so obvious I would say - depending on the return value might be an array you can do pretty much any modification possible for the type of data, but that would be a different likely PHP heavy topic.

Of course you are actually asking about a [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/) that can be used to do such things. To retrieve your post meta you are using [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) - [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1920) - I assume, which is a wrapper for [`get_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata) - [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L252). Inside `get_metadata()` we find the filter hook [`get_{$meta_type}_metadata`](http://hookr.io/filters/get_meta_type_metadata/) - [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L272) - it is variable, depending on the `$meta_type`, which means for post meta(s) it is `get_post_metadata`.

It can be used like this:

```
add_filter(
    'get_post_metadata',
    'wpse162923_change_post_meta_out'
);
function wpse162923_change_post_meta_out(
    $check,
    $object_id,
    $meta_key,
    $single
) {
    if ( $meta_key == 'your_post_meta' ) {
        $your_post_meta = get_post_meta(
            $object_id,
            'your_post_meta',
            $single
        );
        $check =
            'My post meta: '
            . $your_post_meta;
    }
    return $check;
}
```

Note: the above is just exemplary, so make it fit to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could edit the fields when you save the post using the `save_post` filter. - [View Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

**Codex Example**

```
/**
 * Save post metadata when a post is saved.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post.
 */
function save_book_meta( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * In production code, $slug should be set only once in the plugin,
     * preferably as a class property, rather than in each function that needs it.
     */
    $slug = 'book';

    // If this isn't a 'book' post, don't update it.
    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // - Update the post's metadata.

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['book_author'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'book_author', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['book_author'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['publisher'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'publisher', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['publisher'] ) );
    }

    // Checkboxes are present if checked, absent if not.
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['inprint'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'inprint', TRUE );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'inprint', FALSE );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_book_meta' );
```

As the above shows, you can `$_REQUEST` the post meta, change it or modify it however needed, then save it.